# access element inside on event call back

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I'm trying to access a variable inside event callback but getting an error as variable not defined
could some help me on this.

```
el=e.data('daterangepicker')
el.container.find('.calendar ').on 'mouseenter.daterangepicker', 'td.available', (event) ->
  if (!$(event.target).hasClass('available'))
    return
  title = $(event.target).attr('data-title')
  row = title.substr(1, 1)
  col = title.substr(3, 1)
  cal = $(event.target).parents('.calendar')
  date=el.leftCalendar.calendar[row][col]
```

I'm getting error as el not defined
Could some one help me on this.

Comment: This may be missing more code but should you have var el = e.date('daterangepicker');

Comment: coffee script not required var 
el is accessible before the event handler and after the handler

Comment: Didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: Please post the error and desired outcome.